# Add a class attribute with theme_item_list

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a list with theme_item_list within a hook_block_view function.

```
$items = array();
$items[] = array('data' => l('Training', 'training'));
$items[] = array('data' => l('Publications', 'publications'));
$items[] = array('data' => l('Conferences', 'conferences'));
$items[] = array('data' => l('Information service', 'information-service'));
$block['content'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items), NULL, 'ul', array('id' => 'contact-us'));
```

I want the output to be:

```
<ul id='contact-us'>
    <li><a href='/training>Training</a></li>
    ...
```

but the class is missing when the output is returned:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='/training>Training</a></li>
    ...
```

I think I've followed the example on drupal.org accurately, but it's not working? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: This version of the theme_item_list function is for Drupal 6. The code seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The comments I received led me to believe that the function in Drupal 7 is different to the function in previous versions. It seems I was looking at an example for version 6. This works for 7:

```
array(
  'list' => array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#type' => 'ul',
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'contact-us'),
    '#items' => array(                  
      'item_1' => l('Training', 'training'),
      'item_2' => l('Publications', 'publications'),
      'item_3' => l('Conferences', 'conferences'),
      'item_4' => l('Information service', 'information-service')
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on drupal 6

`$block['content'] = theme_item_list($items , $title = NULL, $type = 'ul', $attributes = array('id' => 'contact-us') ) ;`

Please do note you can add any valid attribute to the $attributes array().

Working Example on drupal 6:

`$block['content'] = theme_item_list($items , $title = NULL, $type = 'ul', $attributes = Array( 'id' => 'contact-us', 'class' => 'some-class', 'style' => 'color:red')) ;`

Documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/6